# How to override the implementation of a non-generic function in R

Tags: r, r-s3

In R, I have an S3 class that emulates a 1D vector, and so I want to implement custom versions of `mean`, `sum`, `max`, etc. Let's say it looks like this:

```
my_class = function(){
  structure(list(), class='my_class')
}
```

All the above methods work fine, if I define `mean.my_class` etc:

```
mean.my_class = function(x){
  2
}

mean(my_class())
```

However, I would also like to do this for functions like `var`, which isn't a generic method. If I create such a function, and then call `var` on an instance of my class:

```
var.my_class = function(his){
  # Do stuff here
}

var(my_class())
```

I get the error:

```
Error in var(my_class()) : is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
```

This is because there is no generic `var` function, and it's just calling `stats::var` on my structure. How then can I provide a custom implementation if there isn't a generic method? I don't want to break the `var` method for regular vectors either.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for a full answer but check Creating new methods and generics in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

Comment: Right, but because there's already a `var` function, should I define a generic function with the same name, or with a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [methods for non generics](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/Methods_for_Nongenerics.html), `S4` `setMethod` seems to be compatible with `S3` class:

```
setMethod("var","my_class",function(x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use) {"Var for my_class"})
#> Creating a generic function for 'var' from package 'stats' in the global environment
#> in method for 'var' with signature '"my_class"': no definition for class "my_class"

my_class = function(){
  structure(list(), class='my_class')
}

var(my_class())
#> [1] "Var for my_class"
var(1:10)
#> [1] 9.166667
```

Comment: Sure this works but you can do the same in S3, no need to use S4. Either way, it creates a completely new generic rather than adding a method to an existing generic.

Comment: I like this approach because `setMethod` (and the associated `setGeneric`) are specifically designed for my use-case, and therefore can do useful things like copying the method signature. As noted by @KonradRudolph, you still can't replace the original function in the original package although I didn't expect that would be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own generic with the same name and signature as the existing non-generic function:

```
var = function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use) UseMethod('var')
var.my_class = function (x, y, na.rm, use) 42

registerS3method('var', 'default', stats::var)
registerS3method('var', 'my_class', var.my_class)
```

… instead of manually copying the formal argument list for the generic function, you can instead use the following to generate it automatically:

```
var = function () UseMethod('var')
formals(var) = formals(stats::var)
```

— Of course the above only works if the caller calls *your* `var` function. If somebody invokes for instance `stats::var`, your generic won’t be found, and so no S3 method dispatch happens.

---

Beware that R 3.5 changed the way S3 method lookup works across environments, and merely defining an appropriately-named function is no longer sufficient for the method to be found from a different environment — you *need* to invoke `registerS3method` (not just for new generics like `var` but also for your `mean`!). Unfortunately there’s virtually no official documentation for this function, just some [blog posts by Kurt Hornik](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/08/19/s3-method-lookup/).

Comment: Will `registerS3method` allow me to use the "default" `var` function instead of `mypackage::var`? Also, how does it relate to `S3method` in the `NAMESPACE` file?

Comment: @Migwell `stats::var` remains a non-generic function, there’s no way to change that. But you can call `var` instead of `mypackage::var` if your package is attached (but it’s sufficient if just the `var` function is attached, not the rest; this is possible e.g. via ‘[box](https://github.com/klmr/box)’). `registerS3method` is unrelated to that — but if your code goes into a package, you don’t need `registerS3method`: having `S3method` inside the `NAMESPACE` file is sufficient (and in fact has the same effect as calling `registerS3method`).